# Looking for advice on appointment scheduling process

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm the SQL Server developer working with a small team on an appointment scheduling project where the client is insisting on having the business logic and processes reside at the database level.  I've tried using functions, stored procedures and triggers to handle the processing, but things aren't working out.

Three different external applications are being used: voice, where calls are taken, agents who enter and request appointment dates and times and a web site where users request an appointment.  There are huge timing synchronization issues.

My feeling is that the business processes for scheduling should be developed in a separate module that sits between the database and the external applications.

Looking for advice from anyone who has worked on an appointment scheduling system that involves multiple front end apps and a single back end database.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm the SQL Server developer working with a small team on an
>   appointment scheduling project where the client is insisting on having
>   the business logic and processes reside at the database level.

It is unusual for a client to have an opinion about **how** problems are solved. Normally a client/customer only thinks about the **what** and the team thinks about the **how**.

Unless the client is somewhat technical and has a reason why he thinks it should all be done in the database. In this case I would discuss those reasons because they might already be an interpretation of his own problem and is possibly asking the wrong question.

I would create one web application and have the phone operators, agents and web users use the same application (maybe with different rights depending on the role). This way you only have to create one application build with a single code base.